# Rails - after_save - How to determine if a record was Created/Update or Deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails app I have the following models:

```
Messages (id, title, content, project_id)
MessageViews (id, message_id, view_status)
Permissions (id, user_id, project_id)
Projects (id, name)
```

Whenever a user is added to a project which existing messages, I want to create a MessageView record for every message in the project.

Likewise, if a user's project permission is deleted, I want to delete all the user's messageViews associated to that project's messages.

In my permissions model, so far I have:

```
  before_destroy :check_message_views

  private

  def check_message_views
      .....
  end
```

How in check_message_views can I determine if a record is being created/update or deleted.

```
When created/updated, I want to loop through and check
When deleted, I want to loop through all the project's messages and delete any messageView for that user.
```

Thanks

Comment: Actually, in Permissions, should I use a :has_many => MessageViews through Messages, Dependent destory? Not sure if that would create them though just delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't your `MessageView` model belong to a `Permission`? Then you could set `:dependent=>:destroy` and everything should work automatically.

Otherwise you can use the [`destroyed?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-destroyed-3F) method.

I don't think there's any sort of equivalent `created?` method but you could put your code in an [`after_create`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) callback in your `Permissions` model. There's an `after_destroy` callback for that matter as well if you want to be consistent.

Another sort of hacky way around it is to check if the model's `created_at` time is the same as it's `updated_at` time. If so then it's been created but hasn't been updated yet.